# Amazon EMR Hadoop, HBase version conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hbase, version, amazon-emr

We use Amazon EMR release 5.21.0, which should include following components:
Hadoop 2.8.5, HBase 1.4.8 (see [Release Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html))

But hbase-server:1.4.8 contains dependency to hadoop-client:2.7.4, which is in conflict with hadoop-client:2.8.5

UPDATE:
According to Relase Guide Amazon says that they use tuned version of hadoop lib: 2.8.5-amzn-1.

> Some components need changes from community versions for Amazon EMR. These components have a version label in the form CommunityVersion-amzn-EmrVersion. For example, if a big-data community component named myapp-component of version 2.2 has been modified three times for inclusion in different Amazon EMR release versions, its release version is listed as 2.2-amzn-3.

Where can I find tuned version? How to check the difference 2.8.5-amzn-1 with 2.8.5 community version?
Why EMR release has incompatible version according to official hbase documentation. [Documentation says](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop) that Hadoop 2.8.3+ should be used with HBase 2.0.x